# Sorting by month and year where after 2015-09 comes 2016-01 and not 2015-10

Tags: php, mysql

I am having some trouble sorting my table. I have a code that generates a table from a query. But the date sort I wrong so I get this

Example:

```
    2016-9  84182320    2
    2016-9  MVH82465446 11164
    2016-9
    2017-4  MVH84734664 18
    2015-10 84078897    242
    2015-10 84079056    16
    2015-10 84184764    9
    2015-11 82072021    70
    2015-11 82277363    6
    2015-12 84079056    25
    2015-12 84079070    24
    2016-10 82379452    50
    2016-11 150202  196
```

This is the query:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(YEAR(Orderdatum),'-',MONTH(Orderdatum) ++ 0) ASOrderdatum,
  Artikelnr,
  OrderKund, 
  SUM(Forspris) as Forspris,
  SUM(Levereratantal) as Levereratantal 
FROM orderhuvud 
LEFT JOIN orderrad ON orderhuvud.Ordernummer = orderrad.Ordernummer
WHERE OrderKund = '15' 
  AND Orderdatum between '2015-04-16' AND '2017-04-04' 
GROUP BY CONCAT(YEAR(Orderdatum),MONTH(Orderdatum)) + 0, Artikelnr
```

Comment: Include `ORDER BY` in your statement

Comment: Don't use `CONCAT()` to construct a date-based value.  Use http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-date_format/  Please show your schema

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2943403  I'd like to offer some best-practices advice, but cannot confidently do so without seeing your table structure and data.  For example: all-caps for msyql functions, table aliases, table-column designation, `DATE_FORMAT()`, and perhaps a different JOIN.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `DATE_FORMAT(YEAR(Orderdatum, %c),MONTH(Orderdatum, %c))`

Comment: We saw the update on the answer from scaisEdge but thank for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not order by

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(Orderdatum),'-',MONTH(Orderdatum) ++ 0) AS Orderdatum
  ,Artikelnr
  ,OrderKund
  , SUM(Forspris) as Forspris
  ,SUM(Levereratantal) as Levereratantal 
FROM orderhuvud 
left JOIN orderrad on orderhuvud.Ordernummer = orderrad.Ordernummer
where OrderKund = '15' 
AND Orderdatum between '2015-04-16' 
AND '2017-04-04' 
GROUP BY CONCAT(YEAR(Orderdatum),MONTH(Orderdatum)) + 0,Artikelnr
ORDER  BY YEAR(Orderdatum), MONTH(Orderdatum), Artikelnr
```

Comment: thank you missed that, I ran in to another problem where it now gose 2015-1 and then 2015-10 2015-11 and then 2015-2. Is there an unseen coma in there?